# Copying column values between a range of index doesn't work

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert values in 2 dimensions in excel to one dimension, adding columns one under the other. However, this script doesn't add the values to a specific row range.

I am using pandas to do that. Excel file is here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dfsfJhLFoGiO8_FG4kmZ87JxT2XFBpvX/view?usp=sharing

```
import pandas as pd  

inpExcelFile = 'C:/sample.xlsx'
gridCells = pd.read_excel(inpExcelFile, sheetname='Sheet1')
Filter=pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1938, 1940, 1):
    gridCells_filter = gridCells[gridCells['Year']==i]
    gridCells_filter=gridCells_filter.reset_index(drop=True)
    gridCells_filter.replace(to_replace =",", value =".") 

    #BELOW IS COPYING COLUMN 
    Filter.at[0:30,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'JAN']
    #AFTER THIS, IT DOESNT COPY COLUMN VALUES
    Filter.at[31:61,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'FEB']
    Filter.at[62:92,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'MAR']
    Filter.at[93:123,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[:30,'APR']
    Filter.at[124:154,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'MAY'] 
    Filter.loc[155:185,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'JUN']
    Filter.at[186:216,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'JUL']
    Filter.at[217:247,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'AUG']
    Filter.at[248:278,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'SEP']
    Filter.at[279:309,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'OCT']
    Filter.at[310:340,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'NOV']
    Filter.at[341:371,'Filtered '+str(i)]=gridCells_filter.loc[0:30,'DEC']
    Filter[Filter.Filtered +str(i) != '-----']
```

The expected result is that all columns values are needed to be in one column as desired order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use general solution for all years - reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns, last sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and remove bad datetimes like `30.2.1938` by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', decimal=',')
df = df.melt(['DAY','Year'], value_name='val')

s = df.pop('DAY').astype(str) + df.pop('variable') + df.pop('Year').astype(str)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%d%b%Y', errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_values('datetime').dropna(subset=['datetime'])
     val   datetime
279  --- 1938-01-01
280  --- 1938-01-02
281  --- 1938-01-03
282  --- 1938-01-04
283  --- 1938-01-05
```

Comment: This actually takes each year to the right side. I want to get one date column and its value column. And what about my approaches problem to see my fault?

Comment: @fyec - I understand, give me some time.

Comment: @fyec - Edited answer.